# Ошибка при создании собственной среды в gym(gymnasium)

Tags: python-3.x

```
import gymnasium
from gymnasium.spaces import Box
from gymnasium import Env, ObservationWrapper
from gymnasium import error, spaces, utils
from gymnasium.utils import seeding

from numpy import uint8
import numpy

from PIL.Image import fromarray
from PIL import Image

import retro


class AirstrikerGenesis(Env):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.__env = retro.make(game='Airstriker-Genesis')
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(0, 255, (224, 320, 3), uint8)
        self.action_space = spaces.Box(0, 1, (12,), uint8)

    def step(self, action) -> tuple:
        self.observation_space, REWARD, DONE, _ = self.__env.step(action)
        return [self.observation_space, REWARD, DONE, _]

    def reset(self) -> spaces.Box:
        observation_space = self.__env.reset()
        return observation_space

    def render(self, mode='human') -> None:
        self.__env.render()

    def close(self) -> None:
        self.__env.close()


class CustomObsWrapper(gymnasium.ObservationWrapper):
    def __init__(self, env):
        super().__init__(env)
        self.env = env
        self.observation_space: Box = gymnasium.spaces.Box(0, 255, (84,84,3))
    
    def observation(self, obs):
        img: Image = fromarray(obs)
        reshaped_img: Image = img.resize((84, 84, 3))
        new_obs: numpy.ndarray = numpy.asarray(reshaped_img)
        return new_obs, _

    def reset(self, **kwargs):
        obs, _ = self.env.reset(**kwargs)
        return self.observation(obs), _


airstrikerGenesis: AirstrikerGenesis = AirstrikerGenesis()
new_airstrikerGenesis: CustomObsWrapper = CustomObsWrapper(airstrikerGenesis)


def main(env):
    obs = env.reset()
    while True:
        obs, rew, done, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
        print(obs.shape)
        env.render()
        if done:
            obs = env.reset()
    env.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(env=new_airstrikerGenesis)
```

Сам стек ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю смысл ошибки, но почему она возникает и как её избежать не понятно. Буду благодарен любой помощи.

Comment: Попробуйте как-то так: `obs, *_ = self.env.reset(**kwargs)`, чтобы распаковать в `_` произвольное число остальных элементов.

Comment: Спасибо, так получилось разобраться))